# How can I check if hidden files exist?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, wildcard, hidden-files

Adobe has the option to download fonts, which is a problem for us in our industry. I found the location for those files and now I want to create a Jamf Smart group to check if fonts have been downloaded.

The file location is `/Users/$loggedInUser/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r/`.

The File names are a combination of numbers. Example: `.33805.otf`.

So far I have the below but it's not working. I keep getting a `False` output.

```
USERS="`ls /Users | grep -v "Shared"`" 

for Adobe in $USERS; do
    if  [[ -a "/Users/$Adobe/Library/Application\ Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r/.[^.]*otf"  ]]  ; then
              echo "True"
    else
              echo "False"
    fi
done
```

Comment: At the start put `shopt -s dotglob`  use an array `users=(/users/*)` or use the `-A` option if your `ls` has it, quote your variables and don't use capital variables, you might/will override the environmental variables `$USER`

Answer (score 2):

[You really want to avoid `ls` here.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) A more robust and portable solution is to simply loop over the matches.

Out of the box, the shell does not include dot files in general glob results; but if you include a dot as part of the wildcard, it will expand it normally.

You can't use double quotes around a wildcard, though; doing that will change the meaning of `*` from a wildcard character into a literal asterisk (and similarly for other wildcard characters like `?`, `[`, etc).

```sh
for user in /Users/*; do
    case $user in *Shared*) continue;; esac
    for file in "$user/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CoreSync/plugins/livetype/.r/".[!.]*otf; do
        if [[ -a "$file" ]]; then
              echo "True"
        else
              echo "False"
        fi
        break
    done
done
```

The double `for` loop isn't exactly intuitive, but that's a good way to robustly check if a wildcard matched any files. Start a loop, but only execute the first iteration; if the first file doesn't exist, it means that the shell could not expand the wildcard, and returned it verbatim. (This is the default and legacy Bourne shell behavior; modern shells have `nullglob` etc which some admins like to enable for all new users.)

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s dotglob

for adobe in /users/*; do
   [[ $adobe == *Shared* ]] && continue  ##: skip the Shared match
    # do the rest of the stuff here    
done
```